# Adding icon next textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, textbox, icons

When next button is clicked, textboxts are controlled if it's empty i want to add delete icon near textbox. I tried this but it didn't work.

```
 $(".nextBtn").click(function () { 
      $(".txt").each(function () {
         $currentVal = $(this).val();
         if ($currentVal.length == 0 || $currentVal == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
             //$(this).css({"backgroundColor": "black", "color": "white"});
             $('<a data-role="button"data-icon="delete"></a>').insertAfter($(this));
         }                
       });
 });
```

//jquery mobile

```
   <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
                <label for:"name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="txt" id="name" required placeholder="Enter your name">        

            </div>

            <div data-role:"fieldcontainer">
                <label for:"surname">Surname:</label>
                <input type="text" class="txt" id="surname" required placeholder="Enter              your surname">
            </div>  

            <div data-role:"fieldcontainer">
                <label for:"email">E-mail:</label>
                <input type="email" class="email" id="email" required placeholder="Enter your e-mail">
            </div>    
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.insertAfter(this)` = `.insertAfter($(this))` You have missed this part.

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't close each condition

```
$('item').each(function() {
   ...
});
```

and use .insertAfter( **$(this)** ) , not .insertAfter( **this** );

Comment: No i closed. I tried each function works. I just didn't write my all codes here.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Xb7Mc/

Validate your HTML

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="txt" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required />
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
        <label for="surname">Surname:</label>
        <input type="text" class="txt" id="surname" placeholder="Enter your surname" required/>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" class="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail" required/>
    </div>
    <span class="nextBtn">NEXT</span>
</div>
```

And for your javascript:

```
$(".nextBtn").click(function () { 
      $(".txt").each(function () {
         $currentVal = $(this).val();
         // the placeholder will never be the value of an input element
         if ($currentVal.length == 0) {
             //$(this).css({"backgroundColor": "black", "color": "white"});
             $(this).parent().append('<a data-role="button" data-icon="delete">X</a>');
         }
      }); // close the $(".txt").each(function() {              
});
```